# How to configure Jest to work with Expo SDK 32

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs, expo, babel-jest

I have an Expo app and was using SDK 28. My team decided we should update to the latest version, that meant updating React Native (Since the latest SDK uses RN 0.57) and Babel.

When we updated our dependencies, and fixed our config files, Jest started to give us this error:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined

      at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/core/whatwg-fetch.js:6:12
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/core/whatwg-fetch.js:486:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-expo/src/setup.js:125:16)
```

After a few days debugging I found out this is related to `babel-jest`'s pre-processor not working correctly, even though I followed their installation [docs](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/README.md#using-babel).

I dug around some more and found out that there's a workaround in this [GitHub Issue thread](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2595#issuecomment-440966998).

Implementing the workaround, plus adding [babel-hoist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-jest-hoist) to my `babel.config.js`, made so that the tests started running.

However Jest's behavior is all wonky and the coverage data is not correct (it counts some lines as uncovered, even though we do have tests for them).

I want to know how to configure Jest properly for compatibility with Expo SDK 32.

These are the relevant config files (which are set to use the workaround mentioned previously).

#### package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "6.3.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "sentry-expo": "~1.9.0"
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-jest-hoist": "^24.0.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "enzyme": "3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.8.0",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.51.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
    ...
  },
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/jest.preprocessor.js"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/src/jest.setup.js"
    ],
  ...
}
```

*** Some dependecies were omitted.**

#### babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'babel-preset-expo',
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    'module:react-native-dotenv',
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  sourceMaps: true,
  plugins: [
    'jest-hoist',
    '@babel/transform-react-jsx-source',
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what solved the problem for me:

- First thing, install `yarn`. Follow this [link](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) for instructions.
- Second, ensure your `package.json` looks something like this:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "9.0.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    ...
  },

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
    ...
  }
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    ...
  },
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  },
}
```

- Third, ensure your `babel.config.js` is setup correctly. Here's the one from my project running Expo's SDK 32:

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      'babel-preset-expo',
      'module:react-native-dotenv',
    ],
    sourceMaps: true,
    plugins: [
      '@babel/transform-react-jsx-source',
    ],
  };
};
```

- Lastly, use `yarn` to install your packages (`yarn install`) and to run your tests `yarn test`.

Comment: Worked for me but can you explain why it works with yarn but not with npm ?

Comment: @baraber not entirelly sure, but my guess is that `npm` downloads the wrong/old packages, while `yarn` installs the correct ones. As far as I know the Expo devs use Yarn so they must've tested SDK 32 with yarn only, which lead to these problems with the new version and `npm` installs.

Comment: That could make sense since it look like some dependency issue.

Answer (score 1):

Expo automatically do setup of jest.
I think you must do 'Expo init newProject', then read .babelrc and package.json

Below is result of expo init.
It works well.

```
// package.json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction: it seems like it's a problem with NPM. When I created a new example project I noticed it used Yarn to download the dependencies. If I deleted the `node_moduels` folder and used `npm install` the tests would start breaking after that.