# React Native Expo App: How to get it to run Jest tests

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, npm, jestjs, expo

So Jest seems to be broken out of the box right now, when creating a React Native App with Expo.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. `expo init'
2. Choose tabs.
3. `cd` into your app.
4. Run `npm test`  **Fails**

I googled and tried out the following fixes:

A) Add `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-expo',
  transform: {
    '\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js',
  }
};
```

B) Copy react-natives preprocessor in your own `jest.preprcessor.js' file:

```
 transform: {
    /*
     * Stop jest from falling over on its face.
     * cf. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2595#issuecomment-440966998
     * cf. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22175#issuecomment-436959462
     */
    '\\.js$': '<rootDir>/jest.preprocessor.js',
  },
```

C) Changing the "test" scripts section

from:

```
"test": "node_modules/.bin/jest"
```

to:

```
"test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
```

So nothing works  All approaches result in some or all tests failing.

Does anyone know how to get jest to work with Expo 32?

**Edit:** [Bruno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677328/8331756) works. Additionally, make sure to delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` before running `yarn`. Furthermore, you don't need a `jest.config.js`. And you also don't need Bruno's `babel.config.js`. Here is mine:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    };
};
```

It's so weird that it doesn't work for `npm`.

<s>PS, here is the preprocessor code so you don't have to search it:</s>

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

/* eslint-env node */

'use strict';

const {transformSync: babelTransformSync} = require('@babel/core');
/* $FlowFixMe(>=0.54.0 site=react_native_oss) This comment suppresses an error
 * found when Flow v0.54 was deployed. To see the error delete this comment and
 * run Flow. */
const babelRegisterOnly = require('metro-babel-register');
/* $FlowFixMe(>=0.54.0 site=react_native_oss) This comment suppresses an error
 * found when Flow v0.54 was deployed. To see the error delete this comment and
 * run Flow. */
const createCacheKeyFunction = require('fbjs-scripts/jest/createCacheKeyFunction');
const generate = require('@babel/generator').default;

const nodeFiles = RegExp(
  [
    '/local-cli/',
    '/metro(?:-[^/]*)?/', // metro, metro-core, metro-source-map, metro-etc
  ].join('|'),
);
const nodeOptions = babelRegisterOnly.config([nodeFiles]);

babelRegisterOnly([]);

/* $FlowFixMe(site=react_native_oss) */
const transformer = require('metro/src/reactNativeTransformer');
module.exports = {
  process(src /*: string */, file /*: string */) {
    if (nodeFiles.test(file)) {
      // node specific transforms only
      return babelTransformSync(src, {
        filename: file,
        sourceType: 'script',
        ...nodeOptions,
        ast: false,
      }).code;
    }

    const {ast} = transformer.transform({
      filename: file,
      localPath: file,
      options: {
        ast: true, // needed for open source (?) https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f8d6b97140cffe8d18b2558f94570c8d1b410d5c#r28647044
        dev: true,
        inlineRequires: true,
        minify: false,
        platform: '',
        projectRoot: '',
        retainLines: true,
        sourceType: 'unambiguous', // b7 required. detects module vs script mode
      },
      src,
      plugins: [
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping')],
        // the flow strip types plugin must go BEFORE class properties!
        // there'll be a test case that fails if you don't.
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types')],
        [
          require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'),
          // use `this.foo = bar` instead of `this.defineProperty('foo', ...)`
          {loose: true},
        ],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-function-name')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-literals')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-parameters')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex')],
        [
          require('@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'),
          {strict: false, allowTopLevelThis: true},
        ],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-classes')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-spread')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread')],
        [
          require('@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals'),
          {loose: true}, // dont 'a'.concat('b'), just use 'a'+'b'
        ],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-for-of'), {loose: true}],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name')],
        [require('@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source')],
      ],
    });

    return generate(
      ast,
      {
        code: true,
        comments: false,
        compact: false,
        filename: file,
        retainLines: true,
        sourceFileName: file,
        sourceMaps: true,
      },
      src,
    ).code;
  },

  getCacheKey: createCacheKeyFunction([
    __filename,
    require.resolve('metro/src/reactNativeTransformer'),
    require.resolve('@babel/core/package.json'),
  ]),
};
```

My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.1",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "yup": "^0.26.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native-a11y": "^1.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^3.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-testing-library": "^1.5.0"
  },
```

Comment: Had the SAME problem, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54524017/how-to-configure-jest-to-work-with-expo-sdk-32. I will try to write an answer in a few (a bit too busy for it atm), but don't use the `'<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js'` workaround, it won't work. Also use yarn to download your packages instead of npm.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but in the accepted answer to your linked question the respondent just asks to create a new project, which I did and does not work.

Comment: Did you create a new example project (`expo init`) and downloaded your modules with `yarn install`? Because my Jest tests weren't working until I switched over to yarn. Also, add your `dependencies` and `devDependencies` to your question, please.

Comment: No, I didn't use `yarn` but `npm`. I have no clue how to use `yarn`  Will add the dependencies! 

Comment: What fixed it for me was to get rid of most extra dependencies (was downloading a bunch of unnecessary stuff) and installing them with yarn. You could try to install yarn via `npm install -g yarn` but thats's not the recommended way (worked for me though). Here's their docs: https://yarnpkg.com/en/

Comment: Tell me if my answer fixed your problem, if it did I will also add it to the thread I linked.

Comment: You don't need to add `babel-jest` to your dependencies because `jest-expo` packs its own dist of it.

Comment: @BrunoEduardo I removed the mention.

Comment: why jest only works with `yarn` and not with `npm`? at work, the team decided to not use yarn anymore, but the only way I can get my tests running is if I install the packages with `yarn`. It used to work with only npm but now I don't understand why we need `yarn`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `dependecies` and `devDependencies` seem fine.

- First thing, install `yarn`. Follow this [link](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) for instructions.
- Second, you must alter a few things in your `package.json`. Like this:

```js
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    ...
  },
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  },
}
```

- Third, ensure your `babel.config.js` is setup correctly. Here's the one from my project running Expo's SDK 32:

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      'babel-preset-expo',
      'module:react-native-dotenv',
    ],
    sourceMaps: true,
    plugins: [
      '@babel/transform-react-jsx-source',
    ],
  };
};
```

- Lastly, use `yarn` to install your packages `yarn install` and to run your tests `yarn test`.

Comment: This works, thank you very much. I didn't need your `babel.config.js`. I ammended my post to prime future readers.